# How to change the splashRadius of a BottomNavigationBarItem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, iconbutton

I am trying to change de splashRadius of a BottomNavigationBarItem in Flutter as if it was an IconButton but there isn't a variable that woks as splashRadius. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have some styling options in the [bar itself](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html), but I don't think it has an option for what I think is a splashRadius. If not, you'll probably have to create a bottom navigationbar yourself. (You can take a look at different packages to see how they do it)